# How to place x axis labels on top of horizontal bar chart

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

**Current Chart**

[image]

**Desired Chart**

[image]

Does anyone know to accomplish this? I really don't want to go back to divs.

Thank you!

Comment: did you workout any thing? can you show anything you have tried to achieve what you desired?

Comment: Disable labels on xAxis, then set [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding) / [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding) and use [datalabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) or [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer)

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan! you gave me the right direction, it worked beautifully with data labels!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the offset for x axis label by using the following options of xAxis property.

```
labels: {
           x : 25,
           y : -25,
           align: 'left'
        }
```

Working fiddle created here - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/dtcLn8sm/

Comment: It's a good option to use but it won't work with every graph as we give fixed positon to y.